# How to launch multiple terminal sessions and ssh to machines based on profiles/scripts in an automated fashion

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal

I would like to launch multiple terminals also ssh to certain machines automatically in linux.
Below is my problem  I want to solve.
I would want to run a script, which has the list of machines {Say m1,m2,....m10} which I want to ssh.
So when i run the script/launcher, it should open terminals in same window(using terminator), ssh to above machines and if I had mentioned the password, even login to those machines.
How can I achieve this, as I need to ssh to tens of machines daily, from terminator, but I am too lazy to type in each of the machine IP and ssh to them.
Also, I would like to have the benefit of maintaining many such launchers/scripts, as they may be of different clusters. 
Eg: One launcher should open 6 terminals and ssh to m1,m2,m3,m4,m5 which are part of same logical session(say cluster)
another launcher should open 4 terminals in same session and ssh to x1,x2,x3,etc

Comment: To let us help you stay lazy, you need to show us the results of your hard work. What have you tried so far and where are you stuck? Please [edit] the question and show research effort, the actual (imperfect) script etc.

Comment: Would `tmux` also be acceptable? If yes, have a look at an extension called [xpanes](https://github.com/greymd/tmux-xpanes).

Answer (score 0):

pexpect can be an elegant tool to achieve the automation you seem to be looking for
https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

You can run a given command by passing it to the gnome-terminal (or related).
Have a look here: 
https://askubuntu.com/a/974782/990192